# Showing a literal string with PHP

Tags: php

I put this in Single quotes in an echo, and the &lt, etc. gets turned into their appropriate characters. They do not display literally, as &lt and etc.

[image: &amp string]

How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe tell us what framework do you use? PHP itself doesn't have a feature like this AFAIK.

Comment: Use `htmlentities()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use htmlspecialchars function

```
<?php
    echo "&lt&gt"; //will display <>
    echo htmlspecialchars ("&lt&gt", ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); //will display &lt&gt
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because those are HTML entities. Use `echo htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');` to turn each individual character into an entity itself, so you'll see them literally. Change your encoding as necessary.